# Does Springboot @RequestParam support List<Object> params in get request

Tags: spring-boot, spring-mvc

Springboot `@RequestParam` annotation can pass basic list parameters, just like:

```java
@GetMapping("param")
public String requestParamDemo(@RequestParam("list")List<Long> list) {
    System.out.println(list.toString());
    return list.toString();
}
```

and in postman, GET request `localhost:8998/param?list=1,3,100` is works, "1,3,100" can be converted to List, but how or if Springboot `@RequestParam` support custom Generics such as below:

```java
@GetMapping("objlist")
    public String paramWithObjList(@RequestParam("objList")List<AaParam> objList) {
        System.out.println("objList = " + objList);
        return objList.toString();
    }
```

```java
import lombok.Data;

@Data
public class AaParam {


    private int id;

    private String name;
}
```

postman request: GET url: `localhost:8998/objlist?objlist=[{id: 1, name: "aa"},{id: 2, name: "bb"}]`

I tested in local and it didn't work.
Want to know if `@RequestParam` can do that or any alternative way to implement it.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Hope this suggestion holds good for your requirement.

I would suggest going with `@RequestBody` code will look like this

```
@PostMapping(path = "/objlist", consumes = "application/json", produces = "application/json")
public String paramWithObjList(@RequestBody List<AaParam> objList) {
    System.out.println("objList = " + objList);
    return objList.toString();
}
```

Note: please add some ObjectPaser in your actual logic (for example Jackson )

Postman request would be like this

[image]

Comment: Hi Sri, thanks for your answer, post request worked, but i need get request and @requestParam, anyway i have solved this issue.